# UIProgressBar within CollectionViewCell always set to 1.0 after being in background

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiprogressbar

I'm stuck while working on a custom calendar. Each day is within an `Array` and then put into custom `CollectionViewCells`.

Within the cell of the current day, I want to put a kind of "marker" (I use a `UIProgressBar` for this) to show the progress of the day. Means at noon of today, the `UIProgressBar` should be at 0.5 and so on.

To handle this, I have the following function which return a Float with one decimal to use it in the `UIProgressBar`:

```
    func getPercentage() -> Float {

        var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
        let hours = cal.component(.hour, from: Date())
        let minutes = cal.component(.minute, from: Date())

        let allHours = Float(hours) + (Float(minutes) / 60)
        
        let result = round((allTimeInHours / 24) * 10) / 10
        
        return allTimeInPercent
    }
```

Within the `cellForItemAt indexPath` im checking if the cell is the cell of today, and if it's the case, I'm calling the `getPercentage()` method to set the `UIProgressBar` within the cell accordingly:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        



    //other functionality + cell-setup
 
        
        if dateArray[indexPath.item] == todayAsDate() {

            cell.progressBar.isHidden = false
            cell.progressBar.progress = getPercentageOfDay()

        } else {

            cell.progressBar.isHidden = true
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

So far everything works fine and looks like this:

[image: Image of UI]

However whenever I go to the Home Screen and then back to the app, the `UIProgressBar` is always set to 1.0.

[image]

After completely closing out the app via the AppSwitcher and restart the app, everything works fine again.

Im guessing there's a problem because I use `dequeueReusableCells` but im not really getting behind it. I don't know where the 1.0 for the `UIProgressBar` is coming from, even when I change the default in the Storyboard the result is the same.

Also if anyone has a suggestion to use something else than a `UIProgressBar` im open for any ideas. Actually I would prefer to just have vertical line moving left to right according to the time of the day.

I'm pretty much a beginner and happy for any hints! :)

Comment: I would try tableview.reloaddata() in your ViewWillAppear method for the table view. This should reset the tableview once you bring it back up from the Home Screen.

Comment: I tried     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }   didn't help unfortunately...